getting ContractExecutionError: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract when creating NFT marketplace contract
I am getting the following error when executing and signing the function createMarketItem in my marketplace contract:
Error listing item: ContractExecutionError: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
    at Web3RequestManager._isReverted (polished-market-editor/backend/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:328:19)
    at Web3RequestManager._processJsonRpcResponse (polished-market-editor/backend/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:280:42)
    at Web3RequestManager.<anonymous> (polished-market-editor/backend/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:167:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (polished-market-editor/backend/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:21:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: [Eip838ExecutionError: Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function] {
    cause: [Eip838ExecutionError: Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function] {
      cause: undefined,
      code: undefined,
      receipt: undefined,
      data: '0x'
    },
    code: -32603,
    receipt: undefined,
    data: '0x'
  },
  code: 310,
  receipt: undefined
}

This error is coming from the line after I invoke createMarketItem() and use the tx to estimate gas. Here is the following code with the line noted:
const tx = marketplaceContract.methods.createMarketItem(process.env.DROID_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, tokenId, price);
const gas = await tx.estimateGas({ from: userWalletAddress, value: listingFee }); //this is where it is having trouble.
console.log(`Estimated Gas: ${gas}`);

I am using hardhat to deploy my contracts. Here is the marketplace contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "./NFT.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract Marketplace is ReentrancyGuard {
    uint256 private _marketItemIds;
    uint256 private _tokensSold;
    uint256 private _tokensCanceled;

    address payable private owner;
    uint256 private listingFee = 0.045 ether;

    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private marketItemIdToMarketItem;

    struct MarketItem {
        uint256 marketItemId;
        address nftContractAddress;
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable creator;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 price;
        bool sold;
        bool canceled;
    }

    event MarketItemCreated(
        uint256 indexed marketItemId,
        address indexed nftContract,
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address creator,
        address seller,
        address owner,
        uint256 price,
        bool sold,
        bool canceled
    );

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        console.log("Marketplace contract deployed by:", msg.sender);
    }

    function getListingFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        // console.log("Listing fee requested:", listingFee);
        return listingFee;
    }

    function createMarketItem(
        address nftContractAddress,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price
    ) public payable nonReentrant returns (uint256) {
        require(price > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
        require(msg.value == listingFee, "Price must be equal to listing price");

        _marketItemIds += 1;
        uint256 marketItemId = _marketItemIds;

        console.log("Creating market sale. Market Item ID:", marketItemId);
        console.log("Price:", price);
        console.log("Token ID:", tokenId);

        address creator = NFT(nftContractAddress).getTokenCreatorById(tokenId);

        marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId] = MarketItem(
            marketItemId,
            nftContractAddress,
            tokenId,
            payable(creator),
            payable(msg.sender),
            payable(address(0)),
            price,
            false,
            false
        );

        IERC721(nftContractAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

        emit MarketItemCreated(
            marketItemId,
            nftContractAddress,
            tokenId,
            payable(creator),
            payable(msg.sender),
            payable(address(0)),
            price,
            false,
            false
        );

        return marketItemId;
    }

    function cancelMarketItem(address nftContractAddress, uint256 marketItemId) public nonReentrant {
        uint256 tokenId = marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].tokenId;
        require(tokenId > 0, "Market item has to exist");

        require(marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].seller == msg.sender, "You are not the seller");

        console.log("Cancelling market item. ID:", marketItemId);
        console.log("Token ID:", tokenId);

        IERC721(nftContractAddress).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);

        marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
        marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].canceled = true;

        _tokensCanceled += 1;
    }

    function getLatestMarketItemByTokenId(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (MarketItem memory, bool) {
        uint256 itemsCount = _marketItemIds;

        console.log("Getting latest market item for Token ID:", tokenId);

        for (uint256 i = itemsCount; i > 0; i--) {
            MarketItem memory item = marketItemIdToMarketItem[i];
            if (item.tokenId != tokenId) continue;
            return (item, true);
        }

        MarketItem memory emptyMarketItem;
        return (emptyMarketItem, false);
    }

    function createMarketSale(address nftContractAddress, uint256 marketItemId) public payable nonReentrant {
        uint256 price = marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].price;
        uint256 tokenId = marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].tokenId;
        require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to continue");

        console.log("Creating market sale. Market Item ID:", marketItemId);
        console.log("Price:", price);
        console.log("Token ID:", tokenId);

        marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
        marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].sold = true;

        marketItemIdToMarketItem[marketItemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
        IERC721(nftContractAddress).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);

        _tokensSold += 1;

        payable(owner).transfer(listingFee);
    }

    function fetchAvailableMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint256 itemsCount = _marketItemIds;
        uint256 availableItemsCount = itemsCount - _tokensSold - _tokensCanceled;

        console.log("Fetching available market items. Total:", availableItemsCount);

        MarketItem[] memory marketItems = new MarketItem[](availableItemsCount);

        uint256 currentIndex = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= itemsCount; i++) {
            MarketItem memory item = marketItemIdToMarketItem[i];
            if (item.owner != address(0) || item.canceled) continue;
            marketItems[currentIndex] = item;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }

        return marketItems;
    }

    function compareStrings(string memory a, string memory b) private pure returns (bool) {
        return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked((b))));
    }

    function getMarketItemAddressByProperty(MarketItem memory item, string memory property)
        private
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        require(
            compareStrings(property, "seller") || compareStrings(property, "owner"),
            "Parameter must be 'seller' or 'owner'"
        );

        return compareStrings(property, "seller") ? item.seller : item.owner;
    }

    function fetchSellingMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        return fetchMarketItemsByAddressProperty("seller");
    }

    function fetchOwnedMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        return fetchMarketItemsByAddressProperty("owner");
    }

    function fetchMarketItemsByAddressProperty(string memory _addressProperty)
        public
        view
        returns (MarketItem[] memory)
    {
        require(
            compareStrings(_addressProperty, "seller") || compareStrings(_addressProperty, "owner"),
            "Parameter must be 'seller' or 'owner'"
        );

        uint256 totalItemsCount = _marketItemIds;
        uint256 itemCount = 0;
        uint256 currentIndex = 0;

        console.log("Fetching market items by address property:", _addressProperty);

        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= totalItemsCount; i++) {
            MarketItem storage item = marketItemIdToMarketItem[i];
            address addressPropertyValue = getMarketItemAddressByProperty(item, _addressProperty);
            if (addressPropertyValue != msg.sender) continue;
            itemCount += 1;
        }

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);

        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= totalItemsCount; i++) {
            MarketItem storage item = marketItemIdToMarketItem[i];
            address addressPropertyValue = getMarketItemAddressByProperty(item, _addressProperty);
            if (addressPropertyValue != msg.sender) continue;
            items[currentIndex] = item;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }

        return items;
    }
}

Does anyone have any ideas?

Do the other functions work? For example you can try getListingFee()
